# Как в Android Studio узнать и поменять версию java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, project, version

В Intelij IDEA это можно сделать, зайдя в Progect Structure - Progect (если, конечно я правильно трактую то, что вижу):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в Android Studio, при переходе по тому же пути находится совершенно другая информация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android по дефолту использует Java версии 1.6. Если вы хотите подключить Java 8 версии вы можете в

app/build.gradle

```
android { 
    ... 
    compileOptions { 
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
    } 

    kotlinOptions { 
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString() 
    }
}
```

Android не использует других версий Java, поэтому фактически вы не можете как-либо менять версию.

**UPD:** Как дополнил @IR42

Начиная с Android Studio 4.0 для получения больших возможностей Java 8 можно добавить ключ

```
compileOptions { 
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}
```

и библиотеку

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.10'
```

Comment: Это добавит лишь малую часть от java 8, чтобы получить больше фич, можно с Android Studio 4.0 добавить ключ `compileOptions { coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true }` и библиотеку  `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.10'` https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение.

Comment: Благодарствую !